# MySQL reports: Documentation #1064 - There is something wrong in the syntax used with "" on rule 3

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on an assignment for school, where I have to write a query, but I am experiencing an error.

The assingment goes as follows:
If customer A visits branch 1, and customer B visits branch 1 and 2, and customer C visits branch 2, then you can say that customer A and B 0 branches are separated from each other, and customer A and C 1 branch. Find how many branches two random customers are apart from each other.

I get this error

```
SQL-query: Documentatie
SELECT DISTINCT a.klant_idklant AS "KLANT A", b.klant_idklant AS "KLANT B", a.filiaal_idfiliaal AS "FILIAAL A", b.filiaal_idfiliaal AS "FILIAAL B", ABS(a.filiaal_idfiliaal - b.filiaal_idfiliaal) AS "FILIALEN VAN ELKAAR VERWIJDERD"
FROM aankoop a, aankoop b 
WHERE a.klant_idklant = FLOOR(RAND()(SELECT MAX(idklant) FROM klant) - (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant) + (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant))
AND b.klant_idklant = FLOOR(RAND()(SELECT MAX(idklant) FROM klant) - (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant) + (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant)) LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL reports: Documentation
#1064 - There is something wrong in the syntax used with '(SELECT MAX(idklant) FROM klant) - (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant) + (SELECT MI' on rule 3
```

**This is my current query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.klant_idklant AS "KLANT A"
              , b.klant_idklant AS "KLANT B"
              , a.filiaal_idfiliaal AS "FILIAAL A"
              , b.filiaal_idfiliaal AS "FILIAAL B"
              , ABS(a.filiaal_idfiliaal - b.filiaal_idfiliaal) AS "FILIALEN VAN ELKAAR VERWIJDERD"
           FROM aankoop a
              , aankoop b 
          WHERE a.klant_idklant = FLOOR(RAND()(SELECT MAX(idklant) FROM klant) - 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant) + 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant)
                                       )
            AND b.klant_idklant = FLOOR(RAND()(SELECT MAX(idklant) FROM klant) - 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant) + 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant)
                                       )
```

This is the 
[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrlVD.png)

Comment: Did you mean to pass the `(select max())` as an argument to `rand()`?

Comment: @GSerg, Yeah, that was the intention, but i dont know if the statement good or wrong

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Well you then needed to put the entire `(select ...)` expression inside the brackets of `rand()`, not put it after without any operator between them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your not multiplying the result of the subqueries with RAND().
You should have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.klant_idklant AS "KLANT A"
              , b.klant_idklant AS "KLANT B"
              , a.filiaal_idfiliaal AS "FILIAAL A"
              , b.filiaal_idfiliaal AS "FILIAAL B"
              , ABS(a.filiaal_idfiliaal - b.filiaal_idfiliaal) AS "FILIALEN VAN ELKAAR VERWIJDERD"
           FROM aankoop a
              , aankoop b 
          WHERE a.klant_idklant = FLOOR(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(idklant) FROM klant) - 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant) + 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant)
                                       )
            AND b.klant_idklant = FLOOR(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(idklant) FROM klant) - 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant) + 
                                              (SELECT MIN(idklant) FROM klant)
```